# How to disable special handling of SVG imports in codesandbox?

Tags: javascript, svg, create-react-app, codesandbox

I've created a simple app with create-react-app. This configures webpack loaders for svg files to copy the files and put a public file into the constant. So the following code

```
import mysvg from "./img/my.svg";
console.log(mysvg)
```

prints `/static/media/my.svg`. That's fine.

But when editing/running the same project in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-framework-svdid) it tries to read the svg file (e.g. printing errors about ReactComponent if it's not a proper svg), and makes the handling different. Obviously, I could use the "public" folder instead, but I'd like to use the hash feature of production builds etc.

So my question is, how can I allow to use the same mechanism to get a resolving url path (e.g. valid for img src) in codesandbox and use the default create-react-app configuration?

Comment: The sandbox URL is returning 404. Could you post a new one?

Comment: Oh, sorry, recovered it.

Comment: Note, you can download the sandbox, run npm install && npm start and see it will print ```Path of svg: /static/media/my.080ef5f5.svg``` which actually is downloadable in webpack or production build (while ```/src/img/my.svg``` is not in codesandbox)

Answer (score 1):

I did some digging, and I think this is definitely a bug with codesandbox.

When we use a `.png` image, the string path looks like this:

```
path: https://uploads.codesandbox.io/uploads/user/ff71cfab-643a-41c7-8358-d13e8ce686c9/U6zD-unsplash1.png
```

But when we use an SVG, things fail.

Some similar issues opened on their github repo: [#1664](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/1664), [#3825](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/3825).

The maintainer said that [`svg-react-loader` is included in CRA v2 template](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/1157#issuecomment-426963678), and you can import them as `ReactComponent`, I assume this is what you were talking about initially. I think this is what caused `svg` files to be treated differently by codesandbox.

For now, I guess you can do this hacky workaround:

```
import mysvg from "!raw-loader!./img/my.svg.txt";

// inside render
<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: mysvg }} />
```

[sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-shadow-e4j30)

You would need to add `raw-loader` as dependency and rename the file to `.txt` extension so that it doesn't get handled like an `.svg`.

Long term, I think the best we could do is to participate in [#3825](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/3825) and hope that this can get fixed by codesandbox.

Comment: Sure, where the "default" comes from is clear. Unfortunately one cannot use the path starting with /src/ as opposed to the one generated in the standalone app (/static/media/...), which really resolves to the file content.

Comment: I've updated the question and sandbox to sort out the require vs. import stuff.

Comment: @Christian Ah, forgive me for misunderstanding. I have updated my answer, but you are probably not going to like it...

Comment: Thanks for digging into it. The loader syntax is not supported with create-react-app setup (fails with an explicit message that it's not supported). Also, it does load the svg into the bundle, which I want to avoid. Seems I need to wait for a fix for #3825.

Comment: Weird, I could get a working sandbox with loader [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-shadow-e4j30).

Comment: Yes, in codesandbox it works. But not in the standalone version (download zip and run npm install && npm start).

Comment: Even though the answer did not help me, I award the bounty for finding #3825 before their support team did :)

Answer (score 1):

Answer from the codesandbox team: it is a known issue tracked [on their github repository](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/3825).

Answer (score 0):

If you're want to use svg images,only importing them as React Components, like this,`import {ReactComponent as MySvg} from './img/my.svg'` usually always works. There are other ways as well but I think this one is simplest.
Check out my solution -
[myVersionOfCodesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-jackson-n3bce)